# How to check if day of given date is between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to check if today is anniversary day of bookdate given startdate and enddate in SQL Server

I have the ff. query, but it fails if the dates are month end because the enddate starts with the start of next month.

```
DECLARE @bookdate DATE = '2-28-2023'
,@startdate DATE = '2-28-2023'
,@enddate DATE = '3-1-2023'

SELECT CASE WHEN DAY(@bookdate) BETWEEN DAY(@startdate) AND DAY(@enddate) 
THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS isAnniversary;
```

Comment: why apply the `DAY()` function and not simply `@bookdate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate`

Comment: @Squirrel I also want it to return Yes if lets say the startdate = '3-28-2023', enddate = '3-29-2023' or any other month as long as the day is between these 2 dates.

Comment: @Squirrel - just to be clear, the DAY() function will just return the "day" portion of the given date - eg. DAY(2-28-2023) = 28, DAY(2-29-2023) = 29 .... are you saying that it's a monthly anniversary?  (eg. every 28th day of a month, you would want "isAnniversay" to be "Yes"?)

Comment: @Squirrel yes you are correct.

Comment: Sorry, @Squirrel, I tagged you in my previous comment instead of the OP

Comment: @Ced - are you saying that ``@bookdate`` is allowed to match with ``@startdate`` (or be greater), but must always be LESS than ``@enddate``?

Comment: @Craig it is ok. :)

Comment: @Craig bookdate is allowed to be any date regardless of startdate and enddate. But startdate should always be less than enddate

Comment: Also read [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) if you plan to use `between`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the bookdate to year and month of the startdate

```
DATEFROMPARTS(year(@startdate), month(@startdate), day(@bookdate))
```

and then compare it with start/end date

```
bookdate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
```

Sample

```
DECLARE @bookdate DATE = '20230228';

with date_range as
(    
  select *
  from
  (
    values
    ('20230228', '20230301'),
    ('20230328', '20230329'),
    ('20230401', '20230402')
   ) d (startdate, enddate)
)
select *,
       CASE WHEN bookdate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
            THEN 'Yes' 
            ELSE 'No'
            END AS isAnniversary
from   date_range 
       cross apply
       (
           select bookdate = DATEFROMPARTS(year(startdate), month(startdate), day(@bookdate))
       ) b
```

Solution 2:
find 1st of the month for startdate. Use that as base date and find no of days from that base date and use that for comparision.

one special case is when bookdate is Jan-31 and start/end date is Feb-28 to Mar-01. That is handle with the `OR` condition in the query

```
select *,
       CASE WHEN bookday BETWEEN startday AND endday
            OR   (bookday >= startday AND startmth <> endmth)
            THEN 'Yes' 
            ELSE 'No'
            END AS isAnniversary
from   date_range 
       cross apply
       (
           select bookday  = day(@bookdate),
                  startday = day(startdate),
                  startmth = month(startdate),
                  endday   = datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, startdate), 0), enddate) + 1,
                  endmth   = month(enddate)
       ) b
```

Comment: It is working as I expected, however when the day of bookdate is not available in the month of startdate it fails. Ex. startdate = '3-29-2023'.

Comment: you are right. That does not work

Answer (score 0):

Other Way(SQL Server):

```
DECLARE @bookdate DATE = '2-28-2023'
,@startdate DATE = '2-28-2023'
,@enddate DATE = '3-1-2023'
;

WITH t(lv) AS
(
SELECT 0 lv
 UNION ALL
SELECT lv + 1
  FROM t
 WHERE lv + 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @startdate, @enddate)
)
SELECT (
        CASE 
            WHEN DAY(@bookdate) IN (SELECT DAY(DATEADD(DAY, lv, @startdate)) FROM t) THEN 'Yes' 
            ELSE 'No' 
        END 
) AS isAnniversary
;
```